# KSOAP2 add array to soap request

Tags: java, android, arrays, soap, ksoap2

I'm trying to connect with a web service.
The sample request for this web service contains this array:

```
<Details>
   <invoiceDetails>
    <ItemID>int</ItemID>
    <Price>decimal</Price>
    <Quantity>decimal</Quantity>
    <UOM>int</UOM>
   </invoiceDetails>
   <invoiceDetails>
    <ItemID>int</ItemID>
    <Price>decimal</Price>
    <Quantity>decimal</Quantity>
    <UOM>int</UOM>
   </invoiceDetails>
</Details>
```

I have managed to make a call with SOAP before, but not with arrays, 
so how would I add this to my request?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
 public String getservicecallmethod(String nameSpace, String methodName,
            String soapAction, String Url, List<Info> mInfo) {

        String mResponse = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(nameSpace, methodName);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        if (mPropertyInfo != null) {
            for (Info propertyInfo : mInfo) {
                request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
            }
        }
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Url);
        ht.debug = true;
        try {
            ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mResponse = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mResponse;
    }
```